# Hyundai Santa Fe - Engine Oil Pressure Valve

Tags: oil, hyundai, valve, santa-fe

Does anyone know where a 2007 Hyundai Santa Fe CRDI Engine Oil Pressure Valve is?

Comment: We need to know which engine. Hyundai likes to hide the oil pump and pressure relief valve in the balance shaft unit that is mounted to the bottom cradle of the engine block.

Comment: Are you asking about the [Oil Pressure sender/Switch](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=5467491&cc=3097055&jnid=403&jpid=0)? I believe its the part which tells the computer there is oil pressure which allows the engine to start.

Comment: @jay  Can you provide more data regarding your question?